# ruby range parts

Tags: ruby, range

I have a problem, ruby code:

```
def give_me_all_periods(period, paid_periods)
  # Can you help me?
end

period = [1..10]
paid_periods = [1..2, 5..8]
give_me_all_periods(period, paid_periods).should == [1...2, 2...5, 5...8, 8...10]
```

Comment: Will paid_periods always be within period or does that need to be validated as well?

Comment: Why does it change from `1..2` to `1...2`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def give_me_all_periods(period, paid_periods)
        p = period | paid_periods
        union = p.inject([]){|u,x| u = u|range_to_arr(x)}.sort
        ranges =[]
        union.each_cons(2){|a| ranges << Range.new(a[0],a[1]) }
        ranges

end

def range_to_arr(r)
        [r.first,r.last]
end
```

Comment: def give_me_all_periods(period, paid_periods)
      thresholds = (period + paid_periods).map { |p| [ p.begin, p.end ] }.flatten.uniq.sort
      thresholds.zip(thresholds[1,thresholds.size]).map { |pair| pair[1] ? ( pair[0] ... pair[1] ) : nil }.compact
    end